# ’android:paddingRight’ working with ‘android:drawableRight’

Tags: android, android-edittext, padding

In a EditText,I put a pic in the Rightside of the EditText,
and I use FrameLayout to add a textview showing the remain input count of the Edittext(as show in p1).
[image: p1]

But when the input is too long,it will overlay with the textview,to avoid this,I want use android:paddingRight to keep the input characters stay left,but the result is like p2[image: p2]

how to make the drawable icon stay at right and just the input characters ,like p3?[image]
Thank you.

Comment: For this purpose use RelativeLayout. It's much better.

Comment: Can you share the xml for the mentioned layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be an alternative example, with RelativeLayout:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:paddingRight="30dp"
          />


     <ImageView android:layout_width="20dp" android:layout_height="20dp"
         android:src="@drawable/your_image"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a RelativeLayout instead of appending the button after the text in a LinearLayout.

The resources for Android RelativeLayouts can be found at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

That article is well worth a read

But the general principal is that you can define things like:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/times" />
```

Note `layout_below` and `layout_toLeftOf` above, which define the positioning in relation to other objects

Answer (score 1):

use [ImageSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html)  for adding Image in EditView instead of Setting in Layout